# jest and testing-library controlled input

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I'm trying to apply a unit test in my custom input component
If I pass the **value** prop in the `<Input />` in the **render** function, the test fails.
Does anyone know the reason?
In controlled components like this input, what we can test to have valid unit tests?
Thanks

**Input.tsx**

```
import React, {ChangeEvent, FunctionComponent} from 'react';
import styles from './Input.module.css'

export interface InputProps {
    type?: string
    disabled?: boolean
    value?: string
    onChange?: (value: string) => void
}

const Input: FunctionComponent<InputProps> = ({
    type= 'text',
    disabled = false,
    value,
    onChange,
}) => {
    
    const handleOnChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const value = e.currentTarget.value
        if (onChange) {
            onChange(value)
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <div className={styles.inputWrapper}>
            <input
                className={styles.input}
                type={type}
                disabled={disabled}
                value={value}
                onChange={handleOnChange}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Input;
```

**Input.test.tsx**

```
// PASS WITHOUT ANY ERRORS
it('should has the new value', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup()
    const onChangeMock = jest.fn();
    const { getByRole } = render(<Input onChange={onChangeMock} />)
    const input = getByRole('textbox')
    expect(input).toHaveValue('')
    await user.type(input, 'new input value')
    expect(input).toHaveValue('new input value')
})
 
// FAILS
it('should has the new value', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup()
    const onChangeMock = jest.fn();
    const { getByRole } = render(<Input value="" onChange={onChangeMock} />)
    const input = getByRole('textbox')
    expect(input).toHaveValue('')
    await user.type(input, 'new input value')
    expect(input).toHaveValue('new input value')
})
```

Comment: Why do you expect the input's value to change? It gets its value from the prop, which _doesn't_ change. The component's responsibility is to call the callback, not update the value.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So, in a controlled component like this or any, we can only test the callback that changes its value, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rerender` function that is returned from `render`.

With this, you send new value into your component, input has a new value and then you can assert for that value in the input.

In your case, your test needs to have also checking if `onChange` method is called when you do `userEvent.type()` or if that does not work you can use `fireEvent.change(input...)`.

```js
it('should has the new value', async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  const onChangeMock = jest.fn();
  const { getByRole, rerender } = render(<Input value="" onChange={onChangeMock} />);

  const input = getByRole('textbox');
  expect(input).toHaveValue('');

  rerender(<Input value="new input value" onChange={onChangeMock} />);

  expect(input).toHaveValue('new input value');
});
```